# How does Apache Ignite cache related to database?

Tags: java, ignite

Official documentation leaves lots of questions unanswered.

I need a in-memory Ignite storage where I can keep some data, loaded from 3rd party database. I understand two things:

- I know how to connect to Ignite DB via JDBC driver, how to write and execute DDL statements, how to insert and query data with H2-compatible SQL statements.
- I know how to [initialize Ignite cache using DataStreamers and how to query data using SQLFieldsQuery](https://github.com/apache/ignite/tree/master/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/ignite/examples/persistentstore)

But I have no idea how to combine these two features to make them work together. I don't even know if it is possible. If it's impossible, how should I initialize database for future access via JDBC from external app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. If you're able to query cache using SQLFieldsQuery, then you definitely can use the same SQL query to access it using JDBC Driver.

Here is example, that shows how to access data that was inserted from key-value api with SQL: https://github.com/dmagda/ignite_world_demo, just replace accessing from SQLFieldsQuery with accessing cache from JDBC Driver.

Comment: Thanks Evgenii, I've already found my main mistake: I've been trying to select nested object, and SQLFieldsQuery returnes it successfully, when my SQL Tool produces an error.